# Combine several fields in array of structs BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I currently have a table with a column C where entry for some row R in column C contains an array of structs S = {a: 1, b:2, c: 3}. I want to combine all the "a" values in this table and retain all the distinct "a" values.

That is to say, for R: 1 and C: 1, I have some array A = [S(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3), S(a: 3, b: 4, c: 5)] --> new table that looks like

| a |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |

How would I do this? Thank you.

Edit: Adding a sample of what the original table looks like:

| Row | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Array<Struct(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3), Struct(a: 3, b: 4, c: 5)> |
| 2 | Array<Struct(a: 5, b: 3, c: 3), Struct(a: 6, b: 8, c: 9)> |

Desired Output:

| a |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

Comment: it is not clear what your original data/table looks like  - please provide better sample!

Comment: what the data type of Column `Data`? is it STRING as it looks in your sample or REPEATED RECORD or something else? I think the best way for you to show us a schema of table!

Comment: Yes, it's a REPEATED RECORD!

Comment: ok. clear now :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below simple approach

```
select record.a
from your_table, unnest(data) record
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]